bulk update line item financial type
I have a few hundred line items where the financial type doesn't match the financial type of the contribution (don't ask!)
Is there any way to bulk update? I've tried search kit and update contribs but they don't update the line item

choose the base table as lineitem in searchkit if you want to update the line item

Thanks Pradeep - I couldn't update line item (not a choice) but this did enable me to find and delete . I the reimported cheers

I think you can update entities through the UI by navigating in the Menu to Support > Developer > Api Explorer. If you're familiar with search kit (or the database and SQL commands) you should be able to figure this out. I strongly recommend backing up your database before you execute the query.


Thanks I took the easy way out - deleted and reimported cheers
